# how to apply Array methods onto Collection class in ruby?

Tags: ruby, collections, apply

say that Im working with youtube api, and I encounter `Yt::Collections::Playlists`,
which doesn't contain what I need.

How can i call `Array#reduce` on this collection?

Comment: What is the type of `Playlists`?

Comment: After a super quick sight into source code, you might need to reinvent the wheel [in this module `Yt::Actions::List`](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt/blob/master/lib/yt/actions/list.rb). [See, how `Enumerable` methods are delegated to this `list` method](https://github.com/Fullscreen/yt/blob/master/lib/yt/actions/list.rb#L9)

Comment: @AndreyDeineko interesting, how can i convert Collection into List?